# onpopupload event for L.marker.bindPopup()?

Tags: leaflet

Say I had some code like this:

```
    L.marker({lat: 30.266293, lon: -97.656965}, {icon: myIcon})
        .addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<a href='#' class='test'>click me!</a>");
```

I'd like to be able to do `$('test').click(function() { ... });` after the popup has loaded.

How might I do that? Is there some sort of onpopupload event I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an event on the layer `popupopen`

```
var marker = L.marker({lat: 30.266293, lon: -97.656965}, {icon: myIcon})
        .addTo(mymap)
        .bindPopup("<a href='#' class='test'>click me!</a>");

marker.on('popupopen',(e)=>{
    $('.test').click(function() { ... });
});
```

PS: That the click event will added to the `test` element, you have to add a point before `test`, else the element will not found -->  `$('.test')`